# How to Implement "Notice: This theme recommands the following plugin:xyz" in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, themes, plugin-recommendation

how to add list of plugin that recommended for the theme to run. see below image: 
[image: in this the theme recommend me to install :*kirki*]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TGM-Plugin-Activation](https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation) library is the best choice for installing required plugin.

[image]

Comment: so i have to generate a code via TGM and put my plugins in `plugins` folder?

Comment: You can use this library in a specific plugin or in your theme. if you want using in the theme you should include this library in `functions.php`